# How to configure sublimerope to auto complete python code?

Tags: python, autocomplete, sublimerope

I am trying to use sublime to write code, I want to know how to configure sublime so it can do auto-complete as eclipse does?

I have installed PyQt4, and it's ok if I use eclipse, 
if I write the following code: 
from PyQt4.  After I input the dot, a list of possible matches will show in a drop-down list?
how can I do this with sublimerope? 
I am using mac. Which configuration needs changed?

Comment: Is auto complete a feature of the editor?

Comment: yeah,but I want to use auto-complete ,it seems that eclipse+pydev will analyze the context synatx and then do a syntax complete. I am not sure how to configure sublimerope to do this. As I said,it seems the default sublimerope will not do a synat match

Comment: My point is that it may simply not be supported by sublime - I can't see any mention of auto-complete on the site.

Comment: there is sublimeclang,which is a plugin for clang,it can do syntacx check and do the auto-complete stuff,but it's for cpp.  I am not sure if the sublimerope can do such things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here 
http://messymind.net/2012/07/why-you-should-use-sublime-text-2/
worked for me:

Go to your new .ropeproject folder in your project and edit the config.py. Find the section that looks like this:
?

```
#You can extend python path for looking up modules
#prefs.add('python_path', '~/python/')
```

Here you can add the sources to your site-packages and your current open project, e.g.:
?

```
prefs.add('python_path', '/path/to/site-packages')
prefs.add('python_path', '/path/to/your/project')
```